# JMeter - Variable value concatenation from ForEach Controller

Tags: foreach, jmeter, concatenation, string-concatenation, beanshell

i`m having this scheme in Jmeter:

**> DataBase Extraction** (query that gets some files - note that the extract has a variable bound to it).
   **> ForEach Controller** (runs through the files from DBExt. and stores them in a variable one at a time). 
    **> What i want to do now** is to get each file name and concatenate them in a single string so i can further work with it (count lines with a SSH command).

I`m stuck here. I tried all sorts of BeanShell processors and loggers with no success. I would appreciate any hints or ideas that might help. Thank you!

Later edit:

this is my DB Query:[image]

this is the query result:

[image]

I need a variable with contents like: file1.dat file2.dat file3.dat ... lastfile.dat so i can put it in a SSH Command and perform a line count (wc -l).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need the ForEach Controller here, you can concatenate multiple variables into one using the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code in [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) (put it instead of the ForEach Controller)

```
def concat = new StringBuilder()
vars.entrySet().each {var ->
    if (var.getKey().startsWith('foo')){
        concat.append(var.getValue())
    }
}
vars.put('concat',concat.toString())
```

1. Replace `foo` with your JDBC variable prefix
2. Contatenated values will be available as `${concat}`

---

Just in case it is not something you're looking for you can combine 2 variables into one using [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) like `${__V(foo_${bar})}` where:

- `foo_` is a prefix
- and `bar` is a postfix

Comment: Thank you very much man, i`m getting somewhere now but it`s still not giving me what i want although i understand what you gave me. 
Problem is that:
1. somehow println 'concat' doesnt work after your code so i can see its contents.
2. i`ve put a debug postprocessor and it shows me concat = my global variables but not the variable values from the db query.